# How to split a string of words and numbers into columns of words and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, text, web-scraping

I am trying to split a string from a textfile

```
"Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A 142.26B 131.51B 141.7B 163.83B 162.26B"
"Depreciation & Amortization Expense 10.5B 9.8B 9.4B 9.3B 11.3B"
```

into a a table such as:

```
Metric                                2019    2018    2017   2016    2015   
Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A:  142.26B 131.51B 141.7B 163.83B 162.26B
Depreciation & Amortization Expense   10.5B   9.8B    9.4B   9.3B    11.3B
```

I have used this command:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep="\s+", names=['Metric','Y4','Y3','Y2','Y1'])
```

But I am getting this output:

```
                Metric                        Y4            Y3         Y2          Y1
Cost                          of           Goods          Sold     (COGS)       incl.
COGS                   excluding             D&A        27.56B     26.83B      26.77B
Depreciation                   &    Amortization       Expense      5.48B       5.95B
```

Is there an easy way to split this text into text + numbers? I could split the strings into list and manually reconstruct the strings, but it gets complicated due to the "Metric" containing multiple strings.

Thanks!

Alan

Comment: It's trivial why it is not working, it is splitting on every white space. Is this really how the data is stored? If not you may have to use regular expressions to parse the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can approach this problem in several steps:

1. First we read in your file in a list *(I called it `file.txt`)*:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    print(data)

['Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A 142.26B 131.51B 141.7B 163.83B 162.26B', 'Depreciation & Amortization Expense 10.5B 9.8B 9.4B 9.3B 11.3B']
```

2. We `split` your lines on a whitespace (`' '`) which is preceeded by multiple non digit characters. We use `regular expressions` for this and `positive lookbehind`:

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame([[value for value in re.split('(\D{2,})\s', line) if value != ''] 
                   for line in data], columns=['Metric', 'Years'])

                                Metric                                   Years
0  Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A  142.26B 131.51B 141.7B 163.83B 162.26B
1  Depreciation & Amortization Expense              10.5B 9.8B 9.4B 9.3B 11.3B
```

3. We split your years into their own column using `Series.split` with `expand=True`:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('Years').str.split(expand=True))

                                Metric        0        1       2        3        4
0  Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A  142.26B  131.51B  141.7B  163.83B  162.26B
1  Depreciation & Amortization Expense    10.5B     9.8B    9.4B     9.3B    11.3B
```

4. And finally we rename your columns to the correct ones:

```
df.columns = ['Metric'] + list(range(2019, 2014, -1))

                                Metric     2019     2018    2017     2016     2015
0  Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A  142.26B  131.51B  141.7B  163.83B  162.26B
1  Depreciation & Amortization Expense    10.5B     9.8B    9.4B     9.3B    11.3B
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using `str.rsplit` - splitting string from right with `maxsplit=5`:

```
import pandas as pd

txt = '''
"Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A 142.26B 131.51B 141.7B 163.83B 162.26B"
"Depreciation & Amortization Expense 10.5B 9.8B 9.4B 9.3B 11.3B"
'''

lines = []
for line in map(str.strip, txt.splitlines()):
    if not line:                                    # skip empty lines
        continue
    lines.append( line[1:-1].rsplit(maxsplit=5) )   # [1:-1] because we want to get rid of quotes (")

df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['Metric', 'Y5', 'Y4', 'Y3', 'Y2', 'Y1'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                Metric       Y5       Y4      Y3       Y2       Y1
0  Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A  142.26B  131.51B  141.7B  163.83B  162.26B
1  Depreciation & Amortization Expense    10.5B     9.8B    9.4B     9.3B    11.3B
```